# responsiveness and css-grid and flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, grid

no mater how mush I trying my web site responsiveness for mobile. but I am unable to do it I don't know what I am doing wrong. help me to learn how to make responsive site.

I tried to make some sites

repository-1: https://github.com/nasershareef/Practice-Frontend-Dev-8

site link-1: https://nasershareef.github.io/Practice-Frontend-Dev-8/

repository-2: https://github.com/nasershareef/Practice-Frontend-Dev-7

site link-2: https://nasershareef.github.io/Practice-Frontend-Dev-7/

I messed with size

grid

flexbox

nothing worked my site was not responsive I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

When I'm opening your sites from links in Chrome DevTools and mobile view, sites are looking fine, so where is the problem?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your first site totally looks fine in my opinion. I opened it and inspected it using DevTools but if you expect something else, then please elaborate.

Talking about the second site, you have used an image and upon reducing the screen size, your image is shrinking in just 1 dimension. It is not maintaining its aspect ratio. For this you can set `width: 100%` and `height: auto`. Do let me know if this works.